# How to upload an image file using only javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In form, There is a field of file

```
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="button" value="upload">
```

I want to upload image file onto server but I can't able to upload the image. Is there any solution in only javascript? Please help me to find this answer.
Thanks..!

Comment: I have searched many topics related to uploading image on server, but everywhere i found solution using php or angular or nodejs

Comment: You can encode it as base64 and decode in server side

Comment: _“but everywhere i found solution using php or angular or nodejs”_ – of course you will need _something_ on the server side, that takes the uploaded image and does something with it (like permanently store it under a certain path).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with JavaScript alone, you will need to use a server side language to process the actual uploading of the file.

Comment: what about using node.js (express)?

Comment: by the help of ajax we can't do it?

Comment: Ajax would send the object image data, or whatever the image type is, to php. With php you can store it server (folder).

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job in Firefox, IE does not support FormData, so you should find another way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<form id="data">
  <fieldset>
    <div>Asset File: <input id="image_file" name="image_file[]" type="file" /></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<script>
$(function() {

  $("form#data").submit(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var url  = 'http://server.com/upload';
    var image_file = $('#image_file').get(0).files[0];

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image_file", image_file);

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (status) {
        // do something on success
      }
    });

    return false;

  });

});

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Reflective for your response. I am trying to put your code in my file. Let see what happen.

Comment: Of course jQuery is needed, i'll modify the code to include it

Comment: when I am using your code and implementing it then it gives following errors: detailed error: TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

Comment: It will work in Firefox, IE does not support FormData, and second I forgot to include jQuery ... so I've modified the answer a bit to include the latest jQuery. Reload the page to see the change. Also I have provided an image of FireBug showing that tha file is really posted to server. You will see a red error, but is because I don't have /upload url on my server.

Comment: of course you'll need a serverside script to handle the data sent by JavaScript, but if i correctly undersood you want to send it by JS, so the script sends it by JS. Hope that helps. The example is working one, you can see by the image provided and you can do the check by yourself in the Net view in FireBug (if not installed, install it, the most powerful tool for developers inside the browser).

Comment: So you can rate my answer if you think it's helpful :) I hope I correctly understood your question. You can use pure JS ... not a big deal to avoid using jQuery ... it just make the code simplier.

Comment: when I am alerting the image field it gives (Object FormData)

Comment: How can this be done with pure JavaScript (no jQuery)?

Answer (score 1):

Your web site files are stored at the server. JavaScript runs at the client-side.

The images must be stored somewhere. But the client-side JavaScript have access to the user's browser window (or tab). and user's cache. You cannot write files at the server storage using only client-side JavaScript.

The ways images are uploaded and downloaded:

**Download**:
You send request to the server using JavaScript (ajax for example). In this request you say: "`GET http://my-site/images/cool-dog.png`" This is static request that try to access `images/cool-dog.png` from your **public** folder on the server. Every server has option that allows you to determinate which folder will contain all the files for the **static** requests.

**STATIC** request is when you try to access a file with an extension (`cool-dog.png`)

**Upload**:
As we know, everybody can write client-side JavaScript to the console: Every major browser has debugging tools. And everybody can send any kind of request to your server from [Postman](https://www.google.bg/search?q=postman&oq=postman&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l4j0.972j0j7&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) for example.
It will be bad to accept all of there request. Somebody may want to upload 100GB file at max speed. That may affect the application and server performance or even hack the application.

You need server-side logic to determinate which file is good for your server and where this file must be stored, since the JavaScript know only about client-side storage (cookies, localStorage, sessionStorage, cache, etc...).

Upload process is:
You send request from the client-side JavaScript to the server-side. For example : `POST http://my-site/uploadImage` with the image data.
The server-side accepts that request. For example: `Router.get('uploadImage', function() {...Server side code...})`. Since `http://my-site/uploadImage` is dynamic path (we do not have extension) The server-side Router will wait for this kind request and if it's requested the server-side code must check the file size and extension (.png or .dll) and etc... And if the file is good for your application then you can **write** this file to the server location.

The different server languages and technologies has different methods for processing requests and writing files.

If you want to extend your knowledge you need to learn at least one server-side language and technology. You cannot make flexible applications only with client-side logic.

If you are familiar with JavaScript yet. You may want to learn NodeJS. [This site](http://nodeschool.io/) contains great tutorials for NodeJS beginners.

PHP is also easy to learn if you can found some good tutorials.

[Here](http://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/file-uploads-using-node-js/) is tutorial how to upload files using nodeJS
and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) is another for PHP