# How can I preview a client-side image upload AND submit it via POST request (python/flask)

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm developing an app in Python/Flask that lets a user upload their own image to display as their avatar. I want to let the user preview the image in their browser before submitting the form. I researched this on MDN and in the Flask documentation, and I've got the submit working fine without the preview, but when I add the preview feature (via client-side Javascript) the POST request fails because the form's file element contains no files!

Code snippets below show my test setup. When I use the regular.html form (no client-side preview) the upload works. The file is saved on the server in the designated directory, etc., and the Flask console outputs:

```
File list: [<FileStorage: 'fulano.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>]
Filename is fulano.jpg.
```

When I upload the same file using the "preview.html" it previews fine in the browser, but upon submit, it outputs:

```
File list: []
No file found
```

So I'm wondering if the request.files multidict is not persisting outside the client-side JS function that simulates the click on the hidden file input? And if so, how can I return that multidict from the function and use it in the form submit?

"Regular" form:

```
    <h1>Regular File Upload</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/regular" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p><input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*"></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
```

"Preview" form:

```
    <body>
    <h1>File Upload with Preview</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="/preview" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" id="fileElem" accept="image/*" style="display:none">
            <div id="thumbnailDiv" style="max-height: 200px;">
                 <img alt="your profile image" src="/static/avatars/avatar.png" style="height: 60px">
            </div>
            <p>Your name goes here</p>
            <a href="#" id="fileSelect">Upload an image file</a>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    <a href="/">Return to home page</a>
    <script src="/static/preview.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Preview.js:

```
const fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem"),
thumbnailDiv = document.getElementById("thumbnailDiv");

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (fileElem) {
    fileElem.click();
  }
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
}, false);

fileElem.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);

function handleFiles() {
  if (this.files.length) {
    thumbnailDiv.innerHTML = "";
      const img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
      img.height = 60;
      img.onload = function() {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src); //even without this function, the upload fails
      };
      thumbnailDiv.appendChild(img);
  }
}
```

And an excerpt from the application.py file (this code block is identical for both the regular and preview routes):

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        print (f"File list: {request.files.getlist('file')}")
        if "file" not in request.files:
            print ("No file found")
            return redirect ("/")
        uploaded_file = request.files['file']
        filename = uploaded_file.filename
        print(f"Filename is {filename}.")
        if filename != '':
            file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
            if file_ext not in app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS'] or \
                    file_ext != validate_image(uploaded_file.stream):
                abort(400)
            uploaded_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], "123456" + file_ext)) #this will ultimately be the userID plus file_ext
        return redirect("/")
```

Comment: How about making an AJAX call with `this.files[0]` sent as data? Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29845262/42346

Comment: Thanks, @mechanical_meat. I considered that, since my form will contain both text inputs and the file input, and AJAX would let me submit both types. But no matter how I end up submitting the data, I want to let the user view the preview, and let them keep or cancel the image update based on how it looks. So I don't want to submit the image file for upload to the server until later, when they submit the entire form.  ```this.files``` seems to be empty after the preview is rendered, so I still have the challenge of emerging from the handleFiles() function with ```this.files[0]``` intact.

Comment: I don't know JS well at all, but can you not store that in a variable for later use?

Comment: I learned a bit more. I tried using Javascript to submit the "preview' version of the form, and just before submitting I am able to console.log the name of the previewed image file from ```myForm.fileElem.files[0].name```.  So the file is persisting beyond the handleFiles() function. Still stumped as to why it doesn't reach the server after submit ...